# Extract grouped data from dataset

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, vb.net, dataset

CountryData:

```
Keyid  Data1     Data2

200   London      UK
200   Paris       France
200   Vancouver   Canada
201   NYC         US
```

I have this data in a dataset, i would like to loop through and form a class object like

```
Class CountryData
{

 int keyid;
 public struct MyData()
  {string data1, string data2 }

 public MyData  Data ;
}
```

the output should look like

List countryData=new List();

this countryData should hold data like this (expected result)

```
countryData[0]
           -keyid - 200       
           Data[0].Data1 - London
           Data[0].Data2 - UK

           Data[1].Data1 - Paris
           Data[1].Data2 - France

           Data[2].Data1 - Vancouver
           Data[2].Data2 - Canada

countryData[1]
           -keyid -201     

           Data[0].Data1 - NYC
           Data[0].Data2 - US
```

I tried to group by the dataset, however, i don't get the expected result as above:

```
DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable()
                    .GroupBy(r => r["keyid"])
                    .Select(y=>y.FirstOrDefault()).CopyToDataTable();
```

How should this be grouped upon/any other approach? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve this manually in a foreach statement, it might be a bit complicated but it gives you the same structure that you want:

```
            var myMainData = new Dictionary<int, List<Dictionary<string, string>>>();
            var myDataValue = new List<Dictionary<string, string>>();
            var values = new Dictionary<string, string>();

            //get the first key once
            int lastKeyId = Convert.ToInt32(dataSet.Tables["CountryData"].Rows[0]["Keyid"]);

            foreach (DataRow row in dataSet.Tables["CountryData"].Rows)
            {
                int key = Convert.ToInt32(row["Keyid"]);
                if (lastKeyId != key)
                {
                    myMainData.Add(key, myDataValue);  //add this to the dictionary
                    myDataValue.Clear(); //clear previous list value
                    values.Clear(); //clear previous values
                }

                //add new values
                values.Add(row["Data1"].ToString(), row["Data2"].ToString());
                myDataValue.Add(values);

                lastKeyId = key; //set the current key
            }
```

Now you can use myMainData dictionary anywhere in your code.